# How to deploy the Backbone.js front end part of app to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, backbone.js, deployment

The project, which I am working on, is divided into back end (Ruby on Rails) and front end (Backbone.js) parts. Currently, we are trying to deploy both parts on Heroku, using separated repositories. We had no problems with back end part, but we found out that our front end is not working, getting internal server error 500. We attempted to trick Heroku into thinking that our front end files are PHP. Since, these files are not completely static, this trick was not working.

Comment: Mostly, the problem can be related to routing stuff. can't say further with this limited information.

Comment: interesting, I had deployed rails with backbone to heroku but everything is in the same repo. you can't put them in the same repo?

Comment: @Mr_Green, what kind of information do you need?

Comment: @lusketeer, no, actually that's the issue. It would be easy solved problem, if we were able to put all files together.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as our team found out, that was a front end issue. In case you need to deploy Backbone.js front end part of project to Heroku separatedly, you need to input necessary changes to the server.js file and a couple of others. So, currently we are working on it.